# Can not connect to the JpenMQ queue in citrus-simulator-jms

Tags: simulator, citrus-framework

It would not be bad to expand the documentation on citrus for different types of queues!
 This is the piece of code in which I'm trying to start the Simulator.class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Simulator extends SimulatorJmsAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Simulator.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        QueueConnectionFactory factory = new QueueConnectionFactory();
        try {
            factory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, "mq://192.168.116.21:7676");
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new QueueConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean synchronous(SimulatorJmsConfigurationProperties simulatorJmsConfiguration) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:citrus="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config"
       xmlns:citrus-jms="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/jms/config"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/jms/config http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/jms/config/citrus-jms-config.xsd
       http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config/citrus-config.xsd">

  <citrus:schema-repository id="schemaRepository">
    <citrus:locations>
      <citrus:location path="classpath:xsd/HelloService.xsd"/>
    </citrus:locations>
  </citrus:schema-repository>

  <!-- Test JMS client -->
  <citrus-jms:sync-endpoint id="simulatorEndpoint"
                            destination-name="Citrus.Simulator.Inbound"/>

  <bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.sun.messaging.QueueConnectionFactory.QueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="ConnectionConfiguration" ref="ConnectionConfiguration" />
  </bean>
    <bean id="ConnectionConfiguration" class="com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration">
    <property name="imqAddressList" ref="mq://192.168.116.21:7676" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

When I run clean install, spring-boot: run. I get this error:  `C4003: Error occurred on connection creation [localhost:7676].`

Somebody can help me, why it is happen? And how I correctly to create file context I need some example?

Answer (score 0):

Here my answer: In class EndpointConfig I added few Beans:

```
@Bean
public QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {

QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new QueueConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, "mq://#####.stage.tema:7676");
return connectionFactory;
```

}

```
    @Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {

DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
// factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
return factory;
}
  @Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(QueueConnectionFactory qcf) throws JMSException {
JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
template.setConnectionFactory(qcf);
return template;
}
```

In my test I send my personal object which was injected in pom.Here code:

```
@CitrusTest
@Test
public void send() {

        action(new AbstractTestAction() {
    @Override
    public void doExecute(TestContext context) {
    MORequest req = new MORequest(param1, param2, param3);
    //Method of object
    req.setSourcePort(4);

    jmsTemplate.send("queue_name", (Session sn) -> sn.createObjectMessage(req));

    }

});
}
```